# Students at Table Permutation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out the maximum number of permutations possible for grouping 32 students by 8 tables with 4 per table (non repeating). Here is what I came up with so far by hand but I'm hoping there are more possibilities (numbers represent student IDs):

```
1   32  30  26
2   1   31  27
3   2   32  28
4   3   1   29
5   4   2   30
6   5   3   31
7   6   4   32
8   7   5   1
9   8   6   2
10  9   7   3
11  10  8   4
12  11  9   5
13  12  10  6
14  13  11  7
15  14  12  8
16  15  13  9
17  16  14  10
18  17  15  11
19  18  16  12
20  19  17  13
21  20  18  14
22  21  19  15
23  22  20  16
24  23  21  17
25  24  22  18
26  25  23  19
27  26  24  20
28  27  25  21
29  28  26  22
30  29  27  23
31  30  28  24
32  31  29  25
```

### **EDIT**

The students must be distinct from each other. Notice, for example, how student 1 from row 1 never encounters student 32, 30, or 26 ever again.

How can I figure this out with Python?

Comment: Can you explain what the table represents? Are the numbers student ids or something?

Comment: The question is probably more related for [math.se]

Comment: I was figuring out how many different ways I could arrange them in groups of 4 (as there are 4 students per table). Notice how student 1, for example, never encounters student 2 after the second row. Likewise, it should be the same for the other students.

Comment: Does placement at the table matter, or just that the combination of the four need to be unique?

Comment: I believe you'll use nCr for this. 32C4 + 28C4 + 24C4 + ... assuming placement at the table doesn't matter

Comment: Is "alice bob carol dave at table 1, evan frank george harold at table 2" distinct from "alice bob carol dave at table 2, evan frank george harold at table 1"? Is "alice bob carol dave at table 1" distinct from "bob dave alice carol at table 1"?

Comment: Placement of individual students doesn't matter (I could rearrange the first row as `1 30 26 32` instead of `1 32 30 26`).

Comment: @Kevin Good point, you'd have to have a way of removing duplicates if that is the case.

Comment: Yes removing duplicates would be necessary, so that is why I was confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way that you show your columns, it appears that what you want to do is create a list of 32 students range(1, 33) You then want to shift the list so that you then have the second list

```
l1 = range(1, 33)
l2 = shift(l1, -1)
l3 = shift(l2, -2)
l4 = shift(l3, -4)

for i in range(0:len(l1)):
  print l1[i], l2[i], l3[i], l4[i]
```

Note that shift can be defined in a number of ways including using collections.deque rotate() method or

```
def shift(l, n):
  return l[n:] + l[:n]
```

Comment: This has the same problem as @Raydel Miranda. Notice how in row 1 student 2, 3, and 4 work together again in the second row.

Comment: I tried changing the shift values to 1, 2, and 4 (I see you added that) and it seems to work. Seems hard to believe that there are only 32 possibilities?

Comment: Only 32 students so you are rotating the lists. The point is that you are removing the students as you go and limiting the number of choices by requiring that they stay in order. Note the the shift direction is actually negative in order to rotate to the right in the shift that I show.